# AttributeError: type object X has no attribute Y

Tags: python, django

So I'm a Django noob although I'm quite familiar with the Python syntax. I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError at /dashboard/home/
type object 'Member' has no attribute 'dept1'
```

every time I try to go to my dashboard/home/ url.

I have created a Custom User Model as given below:

```
from django.db import models    # importing database library from Django   
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Member(models.Model):    # table for members' info

    DEPARTMENTS = (
        ('Quiz', 'Quizzing'),
        ('Design', 'Design'),
        ('Elec', 'Electronics'),
        ('Prog', 'Programming'),
    )

    CLASSES = (                 # tuples to store choices for each field
        (9, '9'),               # (actual value to be stored, human-readable value),
        (10, '10'),
        (11, '11'),
        (12, '12'),
    )

    DESIGNATIONS = (
        ('Mem', 'Member'),      
        ('ExecMem', 'Executive Member'),
        ('VicePres', 'Vice President'),
        ('Pres', 'President'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)   # to inherit the properties of the base User class in Django, like first_name, last_name, password, username, etc.
    schoolClass = models.IntegerField('Class', choices = CLASSES)
    desig = models.CharField('Designation', max_length = 20, choices = DESIGNATIONS)
    dept1 = models.CharField('Department 1', max_length = 20, choices = DEPARTMENTS)
    dept2 = models.CharField('Department 2', max_length = 20, choices = DEPARTMENTS)
    #proPic = models.ImageField('Profile Picture', upload_to = 'profile_pics')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Here is my home function from views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url = '/dashboard/login/')
def home(request):

    noOfPosts = 10

    post_list1 = DepInfo.objects.filter(dept = Member.dept1)[:noOfPosts]
    post_list2 = DepInfo.objects.filter(dept = Member.dept2)[:noOfPosts]

    context = {'post_list1': post_list1, 'post_list2': post_list2}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/home.html', context)
```

And here is the required part of my dashboard/home.html template:

```
<h2> Welcome back, {{ Member.first_name }} </h2>
{% if Member.desig == 'Mem' %}
<h2> Member </h2>
{% elif Member.desig == 'ExecMem' %}
<h2> {{ Member.dept1 }} Executive </h2>
{% else %}
<h2> {{ Member.desig }} - MINET </h2>
{% endif %}
<h2> Departments: </h2>
<h3> {{ Member.dept1 }} </h3>
<h3> {{ Member.dept2 }} </h3>
```

Here is my admin.py as well:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import User

from dashboard.models import Member, DepInfo

class MemberInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Member
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'member'

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (MemberInline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
#admin.site.register(Member)
admin.site.register(DepInfo)
```

After I run `python manage.py shell` and call `print foo.dept1` in the shell, itt runs successfully, but refuses to work properly here. Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to access the `dept1` attribute of the Member *class*, but you ought to be getting the attribute from an *instance* of the Member class.

So, your view function should look more like this:

```
current_member = Member.objects.get(user = request.user)
post_list1 = DepInfo.objects.filter(dept = current_user.dept1)[:noOfPosts]
post_list2 = DepInfo.objects.filter(dept = current_user.dept2)[:noOfPosts]
```